# Website API giving fatal libpng error

Tags: php, api, png, fatal-error, libpng

Hello so I'm currently working on a program that will upload an image to my website using the POST method and it's API. Right now everything is going fine and it is connecting to the server and trying to transfer the image however it never actually finishes. When I look in the images folder I see quite a few files with the prefix 'temp' for example: temp_ahgdw9786.png. This is what it is renamed to when it encounters a fatal error.

I'm not sure what is causing this error so I decided to investigate further, I looked through the Apache2/PHP logs and found this line that was repeated every time I attempted to upload:

```
gd-png:  fatal libpng error: Q[10]U[1E]: invalid chunk type
```

I have never messed with libpng so I have no idea what would be causing this or what it even means for that matter. Does anyone know if it may be the API or is a server thing? Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: This program is useful (windows, free) to peek inside the PNG structure, perhaps it helps: http://entropymine.com/jason/tweakpng/

Answer (score 1):

PHP is doing the image processing using libpng and it's complaining about the data you're passing to it. Are you uploading a PNG to begin with? Have you tried other PNG images?

Do you have access to the PHP code of the API that's processing the uploads? If so, you may be calling some of the GD library functions like `imagecreatefrompng` and that's where you might want to start looking for where things might be going wrong. Please provide some code if you can so we can take a look.